# VB.Net: Auto-save data from excel as XML file using console

Tags: xml, vb.net, excel, console, console-application

```
    Using savefiledialog As New SaveFileDialog()
        savefiledialog.RestoreDirectory = True
        savefiledialog.DefaultExt = "xml"
        savefiledialog.Filter = "All Files(*.xml)|*.xml"
        If savefiledialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim filestream As Stream = savefiledialog.OpenFile()
            Dim streamwriter As New StreamWriter(filestream)
            streamwriter.Write("<?xml version='1.0'?>" + Environment.NewLine + tbXmlView.Text)
            streamwriter.Close()
        End If
    End Using
```

I have this code above to save xml as .xml file but it functions like this.

[image: screenshot of running program]

What I wanted is to save .xml file upon running the console... without asking the user to type for the file name. (No SAVE AS dialog box)

What should be done?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem solved and just wanted to share my experience so I posted this question.
What was wrong with my code was this:

```
If savefiledialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim filestream As Stream = savefiledialog.OpenFile()
```

Instead of the above code, just assign the filename right away like this:

```
savefiledialog.FileName = "xmlfile.xml"
```

Or assign a string variable to `savefiledialog.FileName`
So the code will look like this:

```
    Using savefiledialog As New SaveFileDialog()
        savefiledialog.RestoreDirectory = True
        savefiledialog.DefaultExt = "xml"
        savefiledialog.Filter = "All Files(*.xml)|*.xml"
        savefiledialog.FileName = "xmlfile.xml"
        Dim filestream As Stream = savefiledialog.OpenFile()
        Dim streamwriter As New StreamWriter(filestream)
        streamwriter.Write("<?xml version='1.0'?>" + Environment.NewLine + xmlFormatstring)
        streamwriter.Close()
    End Using
```

And it worked well! The console was running then the .xml file was automatically saved. The code shown above is only for saving xml code as filename `xmlfile.xml` as what was set in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated?

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("c:\xmlfile.xml", "<?xml version='1.0'?>" + Environment.NewLine + xmlFormatstring)
```